# Compiled Formula Size discrepancies

Tags: formula, governorlimits, limits

Due to the [incorrect definition of Ceiling and Floor](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KRnWAAW) on Salesforce, I'm struggling with exceeding the max formula size.  Following [Salesforce's Tips for Reducing Formula Size](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/20/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf), I've moved any duplicate formula's into their own field definitions.

When I run check syntax, the compile size is below the maximum (3146)!  However, when I try to save, it errors and tells my formula exceeds the max size (6280).

[image]

Here are my formulas:

**Bill_Month_Function__c**

```
((MONTH(TODAY())+1-MONTH(X1st_Bill_date__c))/Term__c)*Term__c+MONTH(X1st_Bill_date__c)
```

**Next_Bill_Month__c**

```
if(Bill_Month_Function__c < 0, 
Floor(Bill_Month_Function__c),
Ceiling(Bill_Month_Function__c)
)
```

**Next_Bill_Date__c**

```
DATE(
 if(Next_Bill_Month__c > 12,  
   YEAR(TODAY()) + 1, 
   YEAR(TODAY())
  ), 
    Mod(Next_Bill_Month__c, 12), 
 1
)
```

### Update

Took this one step further and moved `MONTH(X1st_Bill_date__c)` to it's own function.  This is straight from the official "Tips for Reducing Formula Size" page 2.

**Result**: my overall formula size somehow jumped up by more than 400 characters!

Also, because this formula changes based on the date, I cannot refactor it to a workflow... My next best option is to write a scheduled batch process...

:facepalm:

Comment: I'm fairly certain that when you use a field that's a formula in another formula, the formula size includes both formulas.

Comment: Well that's fun.

Comment: Yes, the compile size listed using Check shows compile size for "THIS" formula yet when saving it adds the compile sizes for THIS and all referenced formulas. A bit bass ackwards

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? Please provide all details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the guide:  If you cannot reduce the formula field under the length your options are workflow or apex to populate the value on action..  i.e. when you populate X1st_Bill_date__c have a process to then generate the values of the subsequent fields.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work in this scenario.  The only "constant" I could generate would be Month(first_bill_date__c) and I've determined that won't reduce the formula enough to get it to work.  All the other values are dependent on the current date. +1 for the suggestion (this does get it closer)